# Weird behavior of MutationObserver on (google-related?) websites

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, mutation-observers, chrome-web-store

I'm developing a Chrome extension that is using MutationObserver's callback to trigger the cookie-consent & other annoying stuff removal process in content script:

```
start();

function start() {
  console.log('start');
  scanner.observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log('MutationObserver callback', mutations);
    scanner.run();
  }),
  scanner.observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
    attributes: true, characterData: false, childList: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: false, characterDataOldValue: false }
  );}
}
```

`start()` is called directly in content script or everytime I click the button in extension's popup. It works on every website with exception of some google related websites. For example, it works and outputs the correct log in console when searching something on google.com in normal mode, but in incognito mode I get only `start` in browser's console. The same is for developer.chrome.com in both normal and incognito mode.

Next thing is that on chrome.webstore.com (or chrome://extensions inner page, which is not surprising) I'm not getting even the `start`

Btw. it works on translate.google.com or keep.google.com, etc.

Never saw a mention of it in documentation. Is there any explanation of this behavior?

---

**Update**: Not sure if it is google related. I also noticed that sometimes it won't fire on stackowerflow.com or stackexchange.com neither. Sometimes it fires for example 10-20 second later after pageload (when some additional resources, images etc. finnished loading and updated the DOM)

---

If curious: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/provision/napdgmfnfbebjgahggnalabkkfaajldf

Comment: The webstore cannot be scripted by extensions in Chrome by design. As for the other sites it may be blocked by your network admin, open `chrome://policy` and see if it has ExtensionSettings with runtime_blocked_hosts inside. Other issues should be solved by debugging via breakpoints/logging or by simplifying until it works.

Comment: I absolutely don't understand, it seems random whether the callback will be triggered or not, like if the MutationObserver is not created in time when the page is loaded too fast or is cached. I've been able to solve it by timouting the process to make sure it will be triggered so far: `setTimeout(() => { if (!scanner.isRunning()) { scanner.run(); }}, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to get this working on calendar.google.com
Turned out if you enable the extension after the tab is opened and loaded, mutation observers don't work even if you refresh the page repeatedly.

Enable the extension, create a new tab, and it will work there (even after refreshing).